# How to get a list of files from the archive (rar or zip) attached to the E-mail using Python?

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, eml

How to get a list of files from the archive (rar or zip) attached to the E-mail using Python? That is, I have a EML file. I do not need to unzip the files just to get a list. Theoretically possible option when attached very large file and process the extracted attachments can take a lot of time and resources.

Comment: With the stdlib tools, there's no choice but to [parse the whole MIME envelope](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api), [extract the attachment](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload), [open it as a zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), and [read the directory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist). You won't need to read the actual zip entries, of course. Have you tried this and found it too slow, or are you just worried about "theoretically possible"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with the stdlib, getting the first attachment in a simple multi-part message stored as `message.eml`:

```
import email.parser
import StringIO
import zipfile

with open('message.eml') as f:
    msg = email.parser.Parser().parse(f)
attachment = msg.get_payload(1)
zipf = StringIO.StringIO(attachment.get_payload())
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipf)
filenames = zip.namelist()
```

This will parse the whole MIME envelope, decode the whole attachment, and read the ZIP directory of that attachment… but at least it won't uncompress any of the files in the ZIP archive, so I suspect you won't actually have any performance problem to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114952/1440755) tells you how to get the file object (for a zip archive, use the [ZipFile constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile) to open the file, rather than the normal open() function). Then you can use [zipfile.namelist()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) to get the names of the archive members