# python: extract and download an image from the body of the email

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I am trying to read the content of the email. If an email contains an image in the **BODY** part I need to extract and save it in the local
Here is the code for getting the body content

```
def get_body(id):
    res, mail_data = connection.fetch(id, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email=mail_data[0][1]
    email_message_instance = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    whole_body = ''
    for part in email_message_instance.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain": # ignore attachments/html
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            whole_body += body + ' '
        else:
                                    continue
    return whole_body
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting mail attachment to python file object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067937/getting-mail-attachment-to-python-file-object)

Comment: @AriGold It will not be a attachment it will be directly in the body. The whole image will be on the body

Comment: are you already know how to get the body?

Comment: @AriGold Edited the question with code for extracting the body

Comment: can you please edit the return value of get_body and your exception too, thx

Comment: @AriGold sorry I didn't get u. Can you please elaborate what to edit

Comment: test it with a dummy mail incl. image in the message body and add the return of get_body to your question like a sandbox case

Comment: @AriGold added the return type of the email when an image is in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
def get_body(id):
    """Get the body of the email"""
    res, mail_data = connection.fetch(id, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email=mail_data[0][1]
    email_message_instance = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    whole_body = ''
    for part in email_message_instance.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain": # ignore attachments/html
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            print "body" + body
            whole_body += body + ' '
        if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
            print "image content"
            image = part.get_filename().split('.')
            image_name =  image[0] + id  + "." + image[1]
            open(E: + '/' + image_name, 'wb').write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        else:
            continue
    return whole_body
```