# Is msg.is_attachment() enough to get all the attachments from email in python, or should we check that msg.is_multipart() too?

Tags: python, imaplib

I am searching for mails from a particular sender with a particular subject.
I take the first email, and then want to retrieve the attachments from it.

I'm using imaplib.

My code -

```
_, mails = imap_client.search(None, f'(FROM "{sender}")', f'(SUBJECT "{subject}")')
first_mail = mails[0].split()[0]
mail_msgs = [email.message_from_bytes(response[1]) for response in first_mail if isinstance(response, tuple)]
msg = mail_msgs[0]
attachments = [part for part in msg.walk() if msg.is_multipart() and part.get_content_disposition() == "attachment"]
```

My question is regarding the last line -
to retrieve the attachments, do i need to check if the msg is both `is_multipart()` and `get_content_disposition()`

```
attachments = [part for part in msg.walk() if msg.is_multipart() and part.get_content_disposition() == "attachment"]
```

or will only checking for `get_content_disposition()` suffice?

```
attachments = [part for part in msg.walk() if part.get_content_disposition() == "attachment"]
```

Comment: This might be classed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4067937/175584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Possible bug

`email.message_from_bytes()` is not guaranteed to return an `email.message.EmailMessage` object. It returns an `email.message.Message` object, which does not necessarily have the `is_attachment()` method.
So you might want to pass `_class=email.message.EmailMessage` to `email.message_from_bytes()`.

## Answer to the question

`Message.is_multipart()` checks whether the message is a multipart message. This does not mean, that it contains an attachment *file*. It will also match emails, which are sent with dual `text/html` and `text/plain` bodies. If you want to filter multipart messages, this is all you need. If you want to filter *file* attachments, you want to filter using `part.is_attachment()` on the messages *parts*. In the latter case, `is_attachment()` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed the bug a few minutes ago. Which class is better to use - `email.message.EmailMessage` or `email.message.Message`?

Comment: If you are dealing with email messages, use `email.message.EmailMessage`. As I said, `email.message.Message` does not have the `is_attachment()` method.

Comment: The proper way to use the modern Python 3.6+ API is to `from email.policy import default` and then pass `message.from_bytes(bytes, policy=default)`

Comment: I have to agree with @tripleee. Using this exposes a bug reported here https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/69826, where ``is_attachment`` throws an error in some cases. And @tripleee suggestion is the correct alternative. The issue propose another one from ``message_from_string``

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this has been overlooked but [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) has an [iter_attachments](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.iter_attachments) method:

```
import email

msg = email.message.EmailMessage()

msg.set_content("Plain text")
msg.add_alternative("<b>HTML content</b>", subtype="html")
# Add three CSV attachments
for n in range(3):
    msg.add_attachment(
        f"test {n}".encode(), 
        maintype="text", 
        subtype="csv", 
        filename=f"test{n}.csv"
    )

# Send over wire
raw_email = msg.as_string()

# Use `policy.default` to get as EmailMessage object
email_msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email, policy=email.policy.default)
for attachment in email_msg.iter_attachments():
    print(
        attachment.get_filename(),
        attachment.get_content_type(),
        attachment.get_content(),
    )
```

Output contains only the attachments so no plain text or HTML parts:

```
test0.csv text/csv test 0
test1.csv text/csv test 1
test2.csv text/csv test 2
```